# Sharding shoud data be same [MongoDB]

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to set up Sharding, so I created:

- 1 config server,
- 2 shard server
- and master server

Here is the `sh.status` output from my master server:

```
mongos> sh.status();
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("57b86fb87925691e5a11e35f")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "192.168.1.3:27018" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "192.168.1.4:27018" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "shardDB",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        shardDB.user
            shard key: { "name" : 1 }
            chunks:
                shard0000   1
            { "name" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "name" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

So I think it's working but I am not sure if it works OK.

`shard0000` chunk on host: `192.168.1.3:27018` has same `user` data as user data on master `192.168.1.6:27020` when I do `db.users.find()`, so is that ok?

I thought the point is to have different data on different shards and that way to reduce load on main server?

Comment: If by master you mean `mongos`, it seems OK if the other shard is empty. This master will take the queries and distribute them to shard or shards and gather the result from shard(s). If you compare different shards (192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.4), they will have different chunks of data

Comment: Yes, master is `mongos`. Aha, but why I have same data on master(mongos - 192.168.1.6) and 192.168.1.3, and no results on 192.168.1.4 ?

Comment: Mongos is just a router and persists no data. Using those configuration servers it will know where to find each chunk of data and route the queries accordingly. When you issue a query to mongos instance (the master), it will route the query to required shard or shards and gather the result returned from shard(s). I guess `192.168.1.4` is an empty shard because you did not persist enough data using the `mongos` interface. Add more data and you will see some data on the second shard as well

Comment: When I login in my master server:  `mongo 192.168.1.6:27020/admin` I can see data same as on my shard server `mongo 192.168.1.3:27018/admin` . I have `109998` records how much records do I need to see data on the another shard host?

Comment: `{  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }` means that `admin` database will not be sharded. Only your inserts into `shardDb` database would be routed to your shards (`{  "_id" : "shardDB",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }`)

Comment: I know that but I don't understand: when I login in my master server(mongos):  `mongo 192.168.1.6:27020/admin` there is database: `shardDB` which has same data as database `shardDB` on shard host: `mongo 192.168.1.3:27018/admin` also my 2nd shard host not have any data:`mongo 192.168.1.4:27018/admin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121442/discussion-between-vladimir-and-ali-dehghani).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vlad,

Is this a production system? If yes, you should have 3 config servers and each shard should be a replica set with a minimum of 3 mongod daemons each. Your current setup would be fine for dev, but it should not be deployed in PROD.

[Look at this document to see the architecture.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#sharded-cluster)

mongos is a router, not a master. Even though you should always query your system from the mongos, the data physically resides in your shard servers. Again, mongos is just a router, that sends your queries to the right place when you application accesses the cluster.

The reason you currently only see your data in one shard is that you do not yet have enough data for it to be distributed across both shards. As your data volume grows MongoDB will "automagically" create new "data chunks" and move them to the new shard in order to keep the cluster balanced.

I also noticed that you are using a timestamp as your shard key. Using time as shard key is usually  a bad choice for 2 reasons:

- LOADING - If you are inserting data that is time sequenced, or data
  for the last (day/hour/minute) all the inserts would go to the same
  data chunk, and consequently to the same single shard. That would
  mean that your inserts would not scale regardless of the number of
  servers you add to the cluster.
- READING - If your shard key is    timestamp, and you frequently query
  the collection by day, or by week    or month, your read queries
  would be broadcasted to all shards at all    times. This again would
  cause your system to not scale even if you    added more servers.

The problem I describe above will only become visible as your data volume and/or query volume increases.

[Look at this presentation, it gives good insight on how to model MongoDB collections for Time Series Data.](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-time-series-data-part-3-sharding)

Comment: I found way to send data to bouth chunk, I just deleted db and repeat process... But I still have same data as on both chunk on my master host: `mongo 192.168.1.6:27020/admin` is that supposed to happend? How can I know my `mongos` works when I use `find` function?

Comment: Yes, when you logon in your mongos address you should be able to query all data. No data actually resides on the mongos, but all data is visible from it. The behavior you are seeing is expected

Comment: So if I login to `mongo 192.168.1.6:27020/admin` and do query `db.users.find({name: 'Vladimir'})` it will search data on some shard host, am I right?